# Lotus Notes C++ API Get Document by UNID

Tags: c++, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am getting started with the Lotus Notes C++ API. I am trying to get a document based on UNID. I know a specific UNID, but I do not know how to write it to a `UNIVERSALNOTEID`.

I am using Lotus Notes 8.5.2, C++ API 8.0.2, Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2008, C++ (managed).

I am able to open a database.

```
 ....
 //Get and open a database.
 LNDatabase   SrcDb;
 Session.GetDatabase( c, &SrcDb, chrServer );
 SrcDb.Open();
```

Then I try to get a document.

```
 LNDocument ld;
 const UNIVERSALNOTEID u = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
 SrcDb.GetDocument(&u, &ld);
```

On compile, I receive the error

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [33]' to 'const  
UNIVERSALNOTEID'
```

Here is where I need to learn the correct way to pass `u` to `GetDocument`.

Comment: A quick Google search found [this documentation](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/6.0.2/api60ref.nsf/0/85255D56004D3F63852564DA001213E9?OpenDocument). You're trying to assign a string to a structure.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are correct, but the documentation that you linked to is for the Notes C API, not the Notes C++ API. The UNID is a fundamental concept in all Lotus Notes development, and the use of different identifiers and representations in the various APIs is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LNDatabase::GetDocument takes a UNID* argument, not UNIVERSALNOTEID*.

To get the UNID, use the LNUniversalID class.  There's a constructor that takes a string argument, and a GetUniversalID method that returns the pointer to UNID.

Answer (score 1):

@Richard Schwartz provided the useful information I needed to create the following code:

```
//Declare document
LNDocument ld;

//Assign to string, convert to const char *, convert to LNString;
std::string strUNID = "F33DD4EA2E8FD32888257B0A0061C063";
const char * chrUNID = strUNID.c_str();
const LNString * lnstrUNID = new LNString(chrUNID);

//Get UNID *
LNUniversalID * lnUNID = new LNUniversalID(*lnstrUNID);
const UNIVERSALNOTEID * unidUNID = lnUNID->GetUniversalID();

//Get document.
LNSTATUS lsGetDocument;
NOTEID ln;
try
{
    lsGetDocument = SrcDb.GetDocument(unidUNID, &ld);
    LNSTATUS lsStatus = ld.Open();
    ln = ld.GetNoteID();
    Console::Write("NOTEID: ");
    Console::WriteLine(ln.ToString());
}
catch (System::Exception ^e)
{
    String^ eMessage = e->Message;
    Console::WriteLine(eMessage);
}
```